# Way to querry data (tags) from a wordpress database?

Tags: php, functions, pages, tags

I need to query the WordPress database and display the data on one of my pages. I've looked and search for tutorials online but none of them are really complete.

---

I am trying to display a list of all the tags on my website on one of my pages. I know the best way to do this is with php. I've googled and binged but all they give me is code doesn't work or it probably works but it's put in the wrong location. The point is that I haven't found complete instructions to get this done. From what I've binged and google the block of code below is supposed help me display my tags list. Taken from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags).

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

However, if you go to my [website page](https://yourplaybackmusic.com/songs), it doesn't show anything although I've got plenty of tags in the site. I looked at the code and it's very logical and looks like it's supposed to work. But being somewhat a noob in wordpress php coding, I feel like I'm making a fundamental mistake in where I should put this code for it to work on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your page the content is empty.

```
<div class="post_tags"></div>
```

It seems you aren't inserting that PHP code correctly into your page. To do so you have to two options:

**Without using a plugin.**

Add the following code in your functions.php

```
function list_all_tags( $atts ) {
    $tags = get_tags();
    $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

        $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'sc_list_all_tags', 'list_all_tags' );
```

Then, on your page, you will use that shortcode, **[sc_list_all_tags]** and all the tags will be shown, I just used your code, it works, but the tags are looking a bit ugly, I know you can format them right.

---

**Using a plugin.**

You have to install [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) or a similar plugin, in this case you have to add the PHP code snippet on *PHPCode Snippets*.

[image]

In the PHP Code Snippets section you can see all the available snippets (already created).

[image]

Finally, you can copy the shortcode of the snippet you want to use and paste into your page.

Comment: is there a way to do this without plugins? I already tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/ but I think it has trouble finding the the global variable to get data from the database. I figure that I'm going to be using a lot of php from now on so I might as well learn how to do it the proper way without addons

Comment: I just added a **Without using a plugin** alternative.

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere but after inserting the code in functions.php and putting the shortcode on the songs page, I clicked on update and it says error while savings. No tags are showing yet.

Comment: Could you show me the error message?

Comment: Here are the errors and configs: https://imgur.com/a/y18ROtr

Comment: If you pay close attention you will see a closing bracket at line 426, so it's like you place your code in the middle of other code... in order to solve that, you will place the code on the very bottom of the page like this: https://i.imgur.com/WUo47wB.png the way in which you inserted the sc into the page is ok.